# How do I "nice" an already running process?

Tags: macos, unix, job-scheduling, nice

I have this process, "kernal_task", that is regularly taking 80% of my CPUs.  I'd like to "nice" it down to 20, but it's already running.

Is there any way in the Mac OS/X bash to decrease the priority of an already running process?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`renice`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/renice):

If `kernal_task` is PID 2243:

```
renice 20 2243
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RENICE(8)                 BSD System Manager's Manual                RENICE(8)

NAME
     renice -- alter priority of running processes

SYNOPSIS
     renice priority [[-p] pid ...] [[-g] pgrp ...] [[-u] user ...]
     renice -n increment [[-p] pid ...] [[-g] pgrp ...] [[-u] user ...]
```